# Where should the pull-up resistors for the I2C interface be placed in layout

Tags: voltage, current, resistors, i2c

I'd like to understand the reasons on where the pull-up resistors should be placed for the I2C interface.

Assume a PCB, where I have one I2C master and multiple I2C slaves. In that case, only one set of pull-up resistors are required. The slaves are located at different locations in the PCB.

In that case, should the I2C pull-up resistors need to be placed close to the master or close to the slave? Could you please explain the reason in simple terms?

Like, one thing I understood is that, the I2C slave devices should be placed as close as possible to the master. If placed far apart, that would add more bus capacitance that would interfere with the rise and fall times of the interface. Also, if the distance between the slaves are long, then the value of the pull-up should be lower (a strong pull-up), so that the bus capacitance can be charged quickly to the supply.

Comment: Whats your bus speed?   If it's standard 100kHz, the location hardly matters.

Comment: Actually my bus speed is 400kHz. But I just want to understand the theroretical answer and the reason behind it.

Comment: I don't see why it would add more bus capacitance if the pull-up was far from the master. Sure, it might be able to make the voltage right at the master change faster but why do you care about that? The value at the receiver is what matters, but then again the slaves also use the same line as the master to transmit so even this is moot. If I really cared about long busses and capacitance, I would use active pull-ups, not resistors.

Comment: Two interesting documents: https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva704/slva704.pdf?ts=1667982115858&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.startpage.com%252F and more answering your question https://e2e.ti.com/cfs-file/__key/communityserver-discussions-components-files/6/I2C-Bus-Pullup-Resistor-Calculation.pdf

Comment: Why specifically you ask if pull-ups must be at the master or a slave, if there are multiple slaves to begin with? Just to put things into a larger context, if you forget you are working with I2C, and making a single open-collector (open-drain) wire with multiple devices, where would you put a pull-up resistor and why? What difference would it make if the pull-up is at start or end of wire, or in the middle, if all devices can drive the wire low and must read it? Also will it matter if bus is star shaped, linear, branched or random shape?

Comment: The NXP I2C standard docs cover this topic if my memory serves me correct.